# Light HTML Part Matching Optimization

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I am receiving some text from an API that has a little bit of HTML in it, namely `<span>`s and `<a>`s. I will be using these parts to fill out the `FormattedText` property of a Xamarin.Forms `Label`.

I have the following code that works fine, but seems pretty inefficient, with an outer regex and three more per loop.

I was wondering if there is some more advanced regex I could use to better chunk this out, to grab the `class` and `href` attributes I need.

Given this input:

```
one<span class=\"a-class\">two</span>three<a href=\"#a-link\">four</a>five
```

Correctly yields:

```
one -> 
two -> a-class
three -> 
four -> #a-link
five ->
```

Code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

public class Program
{
    public class StringPart
    {
        public string Text { get; set; }
        public string Class { get; set; }
        public string Link { get; set; }

        public bool IsClass => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(Class);
        public bool IsLink => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(Link);

        public string Info
            => IsClass ? Class : IsLink ? Link : string.Empty;
    }

    public static void Main()
    {
        var text = "one<span class=\"a-class\">two</span>three<a href=\"#a-link\">four</a>five";

        var parts = new List<StringPart>();

        var idx = 0;

        // Matches '<span class=\"a-class\">two</span>'
        // &       '<a href=\"#a-link\">four</a>'
        foreach (Match match in new Regex($"<(.*?)>(.*?)</(.*?)>").Matches(text))
        {
            // preceeds match
            parts.Add(new StringPart { Text = text.Substring(idx, match.Index - idx) });

            // a match, has either span or a props
            // 3 more regex, though
            parts.Add(new StringPart
            {
                Text = Regex.Replace(match.Value, "<.*?>", string.Empty),
                Link = Regex.Match(match.Value, "(?<=href=\\\")[\\S]+(?=\\\")").Value,
                Class = Regex.Match(match.Value, "(?<=class=\\\")[\\S]+(?=\\\")").Value
            });

            // move idx for next preceeding part
            idx = match.Index + match.Length;
        }

        // remaining after last match
        parts.Add(new StringPart { Text = text.Substring(idx) });

        // dump
        foreach (var p in parts)
            Console.WriteLine($"{p.Text} -> {p.Info}");        
    }
}
```

Comment: How much does this string differ in html classes ect

Comment: From the looks of the API output, it will solely be `a`'s with `href`, and `span`'s with `class`. No other attributes or tags that I've observed. There could be any amount of them though, from zero to a handful. A few `<br>` in there, but I'm already stripping them out for `\n`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code will produce the desired output with a single regex, though the regex is a bit convoluted:

```
    public static void Main()
    {
        var testString = "one<span class=\"a-class\">two</span>three<a href=\"#a-link\">four</a>five";

        var matches = new Regex(@"^(?<Text>.+?)<|span class=""(?<Class>.*?)"">(?<Text>.+?)<\/span|a href=""(?<Link>.*?)"">(?<Text>.+?)<\/a|>(?<Text>.+?)<|>(?<Text>.+?)$").Matches(testString);

        var parts = from m in matches.Cast<Match>()
                    select new StringPart
                    {
                        Text = m.Groups["Text"].Value,
                        Class = m.Groups["Class"].Value,
                        Link = m.Groups["Link"].Value
                    };

        // dump
        foreach (var p in parts)
            Console.WriteLine($"{p.Text} -> {p.Info}");
    }
```

Let's break the regex down.  Here's the full regex without the escaped quotes (I had to escape the double-quotes when I copied from my regex tester to a verbatim C# string):

```
^(?<Text>.*?)<|span class="(?<Class>.*?)">(?<Text>.*?)<\/span|a href="(?<Link>.*?)">(?<Text>.*?)<\/a|>(?<Text>.+?)<|>(?<Text>.+?)$
```

The expression has five parts separated by `|`.  Each part contains one or more named groups that capture the data that we care about for that part.

A named group has this format:  `(?<Name>...)`

Here are the five parts:

1. `^(?<Text>.+?)<` : Matches beginning text up to and including the first `<`
2. `span class="(?<Class>.*?)">(?<Text>.+?)<\/span` : Matches a `<span>` element and captures text and class
3. `a href="(?<Link>.*?)">(?<Text>.+?)<\/a` : Matches a `<a>` element and captures text and link
4. `>(?<Text>.+?)<` : Matches text b/t two HTML elements including the `>` and `<`
5. `>(?<Text>.+?)$` : Matches ending text including the last `>`

Note 1: This will return zero matches if there are no HTML elements in your string (for example, "one").  It might be best to just handle that special case separately.

Note 2: This assumes that the original string does not have the `\`s in it, and those were just put there to escape the double-quotes in the example C# code.  If the string will have `\`s in it, the regex would need to be tweaked to look for `\`s in parts two and three above.

(Here's the regex in the tester I used to come up with this: https://regex101.com/r/9C5dmy/2/ - in addition to escaping the double-quotes when copying into C# code, I was able to rename all of the "Text*" group names to simply "Text" - regex101.com doesn't allow for duplicated group names but C# does, and having all of the "Text*" groups named simply "Text" made the logic simpler.)

UPDATED: Switched the "Text" groups from `(?<Text>.*?)` to `(?<Text>.+?)` to ensure one or more characters to avoid empty string matches.